# Draw a line with finger and make an UIView follow it

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios4, core-graphics

Ok, I have a View, and first, I want that as soon as the user touches the View (a rectangle in this case) and starts dragging around a line should be drawn, following the path of the finger. Later, when I call a specific method, I want the View to follow the line and of course the line to disappear.

My thought for drawing the line:

1. Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view, and then `AddLineToContext`, then draw it.
2. Use the `touchesBegan`, etc. methods. But later, I have multiple Views in there, and I need to find out which one the user touched. (have fun, there will be between 1 and 15...)

And I still have no idea about the other thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of drawing the path, you are on the right track. I would use the gesture recognizer out of the two options you have.

To make the rectangle follow the path the easiest method I can think of is to keep an array of x and y for each point you are passing trough (don't forget to remove the consecutive duplicates).

So, now that you have an array of points that describe the shape of the path you can start a timer, or better use CADisplayLink, that will set the position of the rectangle to each of the points in the array. This will make the rectangle follow the path.

If you want the rectangle to follow the orientation as well, you will need to use [vectors](http://physics.about.com/od/mathematics/a/VectorMath.htm) to describe the direction in which the rectangle should head.

First you need calculate the distance between the rectangle's position and the point in which it should go next using:
[image: distance formula]
then, when you know the distance you can use `arcsine` to get you the direction angle. Then simply rotate the rect by that value.

Be careful at angle representation (pi vs degrees) and at the coordinates system.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use a `CAKeyframeAnimation` with a path (`CGPathRef`). It does all the heavy lifting of calculating the distances between the points (which can get complicated when you want a non-linear animation curve). For drawing, a `CAShapeLayer` could be used.

Comment: If there is such a thing, you are right, it should be used. I could argue if it is easier or not, but that is beyond the scope of the question. I didn't played around with Quartz to much, my answer was based on the experience I had in other environments. It is true that for non-linear animation curves things can get a little bit more complex, but you also have full control over the acceleration and deceleration (depending on position), so it pretty much depends on what you want to achieve in my humble opinion.